# Have the BaF2 scintillators a strong correlation with the input current that cause the shifting of the centroids in the distribution?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, error-analysis, electronics, experimental-technique

In gamma gamma correlation I suspect the presence of systematic error maybe caused by a non optimal voltage according to someone there is a quadratic correlation between centroids position in the channels and the voltage do you have some confirmation/ references?

Comment: The starting place would generally be examining some not-coincidence-gated singles data to search for a position or energy bias in individual scintillators. Ideally your DAQ would take a pre-scaled sample as you go along, but a separate run can be used if needed.

Comment: As an aside, the spelling errors were not helping you get answers because they make it harder for readers to understand what you were asking. I fixed a couple for you, but was stumped by *"alimentation"*. Not having used BaF2 detectors in the past I don't know if this is a term of art, a mis-translation, a mistyping of 'alignment' with some additional words, or something else entirely. Making sure that it says what you mean would probably help.